# Is QueryPerformanceCounter counter process specific?

Tags: winapi, performancecounter

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(VS.85).aspx

1. Imagine that I measure some part of code (20ms)
2. Context switching happend. And my thread was displaced by another thread which was executed (20 ms)
3. Then I receive quantum of time back from scheduler and perform some cals during 1ms.

If calculate elapsed time then what time will I receive? 41ms or 21 ms?

Comment: [Acquiring high-resolution time stamps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408.aspx): *"QPC is typically the best method to use to **time-stamp** events [...]"* Time stamps are not process specific.

Comment: If you're trying to determine how much time is spent in your thread, look into the [GetThreadTimes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If calculate elapsed time then what time will I receive? 41ms or 21 ms?

`QueryPerformanceCounter` reports wall clock time. So the answer will be 41ms.